# TextView multiple lines using \n not working - Android

Tags: android, string, textview

Here is my TextView which I need to have multiple lines on

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:maxLines="3"/>
```

This textView gets used in a ListView so I have the text being set via my Adapter.class. Looking at the individual XML file used to set the style for the textView when I add a string with \n in it it works fine but as soon as I try and do it properly using the class it does not work and just says things along the lines of "This is some text\nThis is some more." My textView's text is set by this line in my adapter.class

```
date1.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE1));
```

CustomizedListView.class just sets up the ListView and gives the Adapter it's strings required to set the text. Does anyone know why using set strings via a class does not work with \n? I have heard that the line above has to be changed in some way for it to work but I am unsure how. Thanks for reading and helping.

Adapter.class

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        TextView date1 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.date1);
        TextView platforms = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.platforms);
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);


        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
        date1.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE1));
        platforms.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_PLATFORMS));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you have String type here song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE1)? Show us your Adapter class

Comment: @dimetil I know it does because it does show the String but without making extra lines via \n. It literally just shows Sometext\nsomemoretext\n

Comment: it's strange, because hardcoded String works perfect as you said. That's why I think issue is in song object type.

Comment: @dimetil I have added it to the post

Comment: did you try to play with android:singleLine="false" or android:lines="3" ?

Comment: I tried android:lines="3" but that did nothing. I shall try using singleLine now.

Comment: @dimetil That did not work.

Comment: I have same problem here.I tested android:lines, android:maxLines and android:inputType but all not worked

Comment: Same problem. Any chance?